# Zabbix Discovery Rule by custom script: need any advices

Tags: python, json, zabbix

I'm trying to make discovery rule to add file size monitor. But when I add my Template to Host, zabbix says me:

> Value should be a JSON object

- Zabbix Agent (daemon) v2.2.10 (revision 54806) (10 August 2015)
- Zabbix server v2.2.9 (revision 52686) (12 March 2015)

I've written the python-script:

```
import os
import sys
import json

logdir = sys.argv[1]

data = []

for (logdir, _, files) in os.walk(logdir):
        for f in files:
                if f.endswith(".log"):
                        path = os.path.join(logdir, f)
                        data.append({'#LOGFILEPATH':path})
                        jsondata = json.dumps(data)

print jsondata
```

It works fine and gets follows:

```
[{"#LOGFILEPATH": "/opt/logs/projects/cms/cms.log"}, {"#LOGFILEPATH": "/opt/logs/projects/books/nginx.log"}]
```

I've checked it by jsonlint.com - valid JSON.

UserParameter in conf.d:

```
UserParameter = discovery.logfile.path, python /opt/scripts/zabbix/find.logfile.path.and.size.py /opt/logs/
```

There are attachments show my discovery configuration:

[image]

[image]

User *zabbix* has permission to directory with script and logs.

Comment: i have the same problem , are you solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes, my problem was I missed brackets {}
Feel free describe your problem here if my advice won't help you

Comment: thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

It has to make the array a value with a key of "data".

```
print json.dumps({"data": data})
```

so it produces...

```
{ "data": [{"#LOGFILEPATH": "/opt/logs/projects/cms/cms.log"}, {"#LOGFILEPATH": "/opt/logs/projects/books/nginx.log"}] }
```

And macro {#LOGFILEPATH} should be in brackets **{}**